# null return when i should be getting a <String> **edited**

Tags: java, string, android-studio, null, return

**edited** forgot to include actual problem.

Soo i am aware my files are returning null because of my "GetData()" call which is flowing through the rest of my scrips causing an error. however, I do not know how to prevent that. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

**issue**
the error i am getting is

    `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.toArray()' on a null object reference`

from my understanding when i use the line

`titles = readRss.titles;`

it pulls a null response through this order.ReadRss > ProcessXml() > Getdata()
and because of get data being a "try" "catch" section its returning both the xmldoc and null.

when i log inside my ProcessXml() i can get a full list of titles and i can log the feed items separately however if i try to log outside of that it returns null.

what am i misunderstanding.

ReadRss script:

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
ArrayList<String>titles;


BlankFragment context;
String address="https://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml";
//ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
URL url;
public ReadRss(BlankFragment context, RecyclerView recyclerView){
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    this.context=context;
   // progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
   // progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}



@Override
public void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //progressDialog.dismiss();


}

@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    ProcessXml(Getdata());
    return null;
}


public ArrayList<String> ProcessXml(Document data) {

    if (data!=null) {
        titles=new ArrayList<>();
        feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root=data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel=root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items=channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){
            Node currentchild=items.item(i);
            if (currentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds=currentchild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0;j<itemchilds.getLength();j++){
                    Node current=itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                        item.setTitle(current.getTextContent());
                        titles.add(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                        item.setDescription(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                        item.setPubDate(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                        item.setLink(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                        String url=current.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                        item.setThumbnailUrl(url);
                    }

                }
                feedItems.add(item);
                Log.d("hello", item.getTitle());


            }

        }
    }

    return titles;


}

public Document Getdata(){
    try{

        url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    return null;
}




}
```

BlankFragment script calling for titles.

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
ArrayList<String>titles;

String address="https://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml";
URL url;



public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(this, rv);
    readRss.getClass();




    titles = readRss.titles;



    String[] display_titles = (String[]) titles.toArray();











    //Document data = readRss.Getdata();
    //ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems = readRss.ProcessXml(data);



    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(display_titles);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}




}
```

Comment: Did my answer below help you out? You could test it out by logging when 'titles' is instantiated and when it is used - that'd let you know which happens first

Comment: Sorry the holidays have had me away. I am just now getting back to this project. Thank you, it did help me alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a race condition, although it sounds like one path always wins the race.
You are using 2 threads;

1. Thread 1 (maybe the UI thread) - create ReadRss - read 'titles'
2. Background thread - execute GetData() - execute ProcessXml() - set 'titles'

If the main thread gets to the point of reading 'titles' before the background thread gets around to instantiating it - then 'titles' will be null.

Maybe after creating the AsyncTask you can carry on to create the View - show "Loading" where the Titles will go. Then when the AsyncTask is done it can update the View with the Titles - onPostExecute().

Comment: This helped me realize what I did wrong however, I dont know how to fix it. At least this way I have a better understanding of what needs to be done.